# File is not read (ifstream)

Tags: c++, vector, ifstream

Hi I have the following code and can not understand why it doesn't read the file !
What I did wrong? Though the .txt file is written with data and the directory is correct.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
vector<string> v;

ifstream in("E:\vector.txt");
string line;
while(getline(in, line))
v.push_back(line); // Add the line to the end
// Add line numbers:
cout<<"v.size()="<<v.size();
for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
cout << i << ": " << v[i] << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ifstream in("E:\vector.txt");
```

Whoops! This does not open `E:\vector.txt`. Backslashes introduce *escape sequences* in string literals. I don't know what `"\v"` is, but it's not the character `\` followed by the character `v`.

**You need to escape the backslash.**

```
ifstream in("E:\\vector.txt");
```

Comment: Alternatively use a [raw string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) `ifstream in(R"raw(E:\vector.txt)raw")`.

Comment: Thanks man, that helped, I forgot that there are things like : "\v" , "\n", "\t"...

Comment: What does the R"raw(...)raw" ? can you explain?

Comment: @MrCatalin4ic: Look up "C++ raw string literals".

Answer (score 0):

```
ifstream in("E:\vector.txt");
```

should be

```
ifstream in("E:\\vector.txt");
```

You could use it also as

```
in.open ("E:\\vector.txt", std::ifstream::in);
```

Comment: _"Member for 2 years, 5 months"_ Also there's a preview pane before you submit your answer.

Comment: I had once signed up with facebook, but never stayed an active member. That was probably 2 years, 5 months ago :)